# Ckeditor in django not working in production

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

Django-ckeditor works fine on local server but does not works in production.

Not Found: /static/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js

Answer (score 4):

have you tried something like

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: yes doesn't work either. command runs successfully but no files are copied in staticfiles directory.

Comment: the is package called WhiteNoise hope it fixeds you static files missing run the command `pip install whitenoise` hope it fixes your problem, i once used it and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by loading these resources on the base admin template, hope it helps!

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% block extrahead %}
    {% load static %}
    <script>window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "{% static '/ckeditor/ckeditor/' %}";</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js' %}"
            data-ckeditor-basepath="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/' %}" id="ckeditor-init-script"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```